# Eclipse error in module, am I not formatting correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse I am getting a error code for

'Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)'

I don't really understand how modules should be formatted and was hoping someone could please explain what I am doing wrong.

```
module math{
    class DoMath{
        public void main(String[] arguments) {
            double score = 1.0 + 2.0 * 3.0;
            System.out.println(score);
            score = score / 2.0;
            System.out.println(score);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the usage of `module` Here is a [link](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) explaining the new module system in java. 
Maybe you wanted to associate the class with a `package`?

```
package com.mycompany.math;
public class DoMath {
    public void main(String[] arguments) {
        double score = 1.0 + 2.0 * 3.0;
        System.out.println(score);
        score = score / 2.0;
        System.out.println(score);
    }
}
```

You can then declare a `module` (a module-info.java file)

```
module mathModule {
    exports com.mycompany.math;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense.